# Hardware/software to project video wirelessly?

Tags: video, wireless

Anyone have any recommendations for ways to do screensharing of video on a Mac wirelessly over WiFi to a projector? In a solution that doesn't require plugging in some kind of USB dongle.

Comment: It sounds like you need a WiFi-enabled projector. I have no idea if these exist, but if they do, I'm sure they'll ship with the software you need to use them.

Comment: Meta discussion of this and questions like it [here](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here).

Comment: @Warrior Bob: Sounds like it has production qualities to me. I know I'm tired of running video cables to projectors whenever I'm doing a show that involves projection.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi enabled projectors have been around for several years, [at least](http://www.projectorcentral.com/wi-fi.htm).

A cursory Google search for "wifi enabled projector" turns up that and several other articles, plus reviews and some product listings. The primary complaint seems to be bandwidth; however I did not find any reviews including more recent Wi-Fi standards like 802.11g/n.

That said, it was a **cursory** search. I saw lots of other results that I didn't have time to click on. Some of them looked a lot more current, and I did find something that looks like a present-day product listing of wireless projectors.

My advice would be to shop around, read reviews, and get a good return/exchange policy if you decide to buy one (so you can test it with relatively low risk).